# Limit the frequency of calls to onEdit

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-api

I wrote some scripts using the script editor to automate some google spread-sheet tasks.
I would like to do a few things after the user interacts with my users sheets, .e.g update some background sheets that start with _.

I wrote the following:

```
function onEdit(e){

  var range = e.range;
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()[0]!='_'){ 

//It is an user edit!  

  UpdateOtherHiddenTables()

  }

};
```

My problem is that   UpdateOtherHiddenTables() takes quite a while, like 2 mins, and it is triggered on any user edit so it is not ideal.
How would you make sure that after a user has interacted with a sheet, that  UpdateOtherHiddenTables() is called, but not too often?

Comment: do you know the range of the edit cells that you want triggering the `UpdateOtherHiddenTables`? if so you can compare `check_update_range` and `e.range` and if the edited cells are within the `check_update_range`  - run `UpdateOtherHiddenTables()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [Script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) in combination with a [timed trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).  The on-Edit trigger only records the fact that the Spreadsheet was edited:

```
function recordEdit() {
  var sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  sp.setProperty("edited", "yes");
}
```

This function needs to be run by an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), simple onEdit won't provide the authorization necessary to modify script properties.

The `UpdateOtherHiddenTables` function is set to run every 10 minutes, or every hour, or whatever interval you want. It checks whether a refresh is needed.

```
function UpdateOtherHiddenTables() {
  var sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  if (sp.getProperty("edited") == "yes") {
    // update stuff
    sp.setProperty("edited", "no");
  }
}
```

By the way: onEdit is only triggered by user edits. A script changing the values in a spreadsheet will not fire that trigger.

I'm using string values instead of Boolean, because Properties stringifies everything. Storing `false` gets you back the string `"false"`, which is truthy...